# Terraform getting error when configuring S3 Backend in Github Actions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform, github-actions

**backend/vda-dev.backend.tfvars** is not recognized in github actions

[image]

[image]

i also tried to add the backend variables inside main.tf and simply run **terraform init** in .yml file, but it was the same error
[image]

Comment: Do you have AWS credentials set up in any way? Sounds like your github action does not have any credentials and therefore cannot talk to S3.

Comment: the connection to aws is done automatically through the framework in the terminal (aws sso login).

Comment: UPDATE. I fixed it by adding an aws authentication step. Thanks!